# spark structured streaming (java): task not serializable

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

IN below code i am trying to read avro message from a kafka topic, and within the map method, where I use KafkaAvroDecoder fromBytes method, it seems to cause the task not serializable exception, how do i decode the avro messages ?

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

```
    Properties decoderProps = new Properties();
    decoderProps.put("schema.registry.url", SCHEMA_REG_URL);
    //decoderProps.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, "true");

    KafkaAvroDecoder decoder = new KafkaAvroDecoder(new VerifiableProperties(decoderProps));


    SparkSession spark = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .appName("JavaCount1").master("local[2]")
        .config("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-Xss4M")
        .getOrCreate();

    Dataset<Row> ds1 = spark
        .readStream()
        .format("kafka")
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", HOSTS)
        .option("subscribe", "systemDec200Message")
        .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
        .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 1)
        .load();



    Dataset<String> ds2 = ds1.map(m-> {
        GenericData.Record data = (GenericData.Record)decoder.fromBytes((byte[]) m.get(1));

        return "sddasdadasdsadas";
}, Encoders.STRING());





    StreamingQuery query = ds2.writeStream()
        .outputMode("append")
        .format("console")
        .trigger(ProcessingTime.apply(15))
        .start();

    query.awaitTermination();
}
```

i get the exception as below,

17/04/12 16:51:06 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 329.145119 ms 17/04/12 16:51:07 ERROR StreamExecution: Query [id = 1d56386c-3fba-4978-8565-6b9c880d4fce, runId = b7bbb8d8-b52d-4c14-9dec-bc9cb41f8d77] terminated with error org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:298) at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288) at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108) at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2094) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1.apply(RDD.scala:840) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1.apply(RDD.scala:839) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex(RDD.scala:839) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:371) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:135) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)

Comment: For any `Task not serializable`, there is part of the stacktrace that tells you exactly what is being serialized

Answer (score 0):

The serialization issue went away after moving the KAFKA AVRO DECODER declaration within the lambda scope (within the map call)  but, now a different exception at runtime,

```
org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 116, Column 101: No applicable constructor/method found for actual parameters "long"; candidates are: "java.lang.Integer(int)", "java.lang.Integer(java.lang.String)"
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileError(UnitCompiler.java:10174)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.findMostSpecificIInvocable(UnitCompiler.java:7559)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.invokeConstructor(UnitCompiler.java:6505)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileGet2(UnitCompiler.java:4126)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$7600(UnitCompiler.java:185)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$10.visitNewClassInstance(UnitCompiler.java:3275)
    at org.codehaus.janino.Java$NewClassInstance.accept(Java.java:4085)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileGet(UnitCompiler.java:3290)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileGetValue(UnitCompiler.java:4368)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileGet2(UnitCompiler.java:3571)
```

Comment: 116th line is   final java.lang.Integer deserializetoobject_value10 = deserializetoobject_resultIsNull3 ? null : new java.lang.Integer(deserializetoobject_argValue3);
/* 117 */         deserializetoobject_javaBean.setOffset(deserializetoobject_value10);
/* 118 */